# Pushing to UINavigationViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I'm doing a login view, which retrieves data and when everything goes well it should move from Login View (UIViewController) to the Navigation controller(UINavigationController) which in his turn should serve as root view controller and move the user to the main view(UIViewController).
The problem is when i reach to the code that works just fine with me inside other classes, it does nothing here, not even throwing exceptions to handle here's my code

```
   func moveToMainView(){
    let navigationControllerView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavControllerView") as! UINavigationController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigationControllerView, animated: true)

}
```

I searched to find if there any special case for UINavigationController, but no luck so far... hope you can help me

Comment: BTW, if I navigated to the UINavigationController using direct segue from the storyboard " not programmatically " it works just fine

Comment: I suggest modifying how you handle your application's login related navigation. A common pattern for handling login is to organize your flow so that the loginVC is presented modally from your mainVC if a user isn't currently logged in (in either viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear, whichever is more appropriate for your use case), and dismissing it upon successful user authentication. By doing this, you ensure that your loginVC is only alive for as long as you need it rather than having it at the bottom of your stack the whole time your app is used.

Comment: well, to be honest I left the login view to the end of the app. now the app is fully working, all i need is to fix this problem and I shall demo the app and upload after customer approval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around the issue and placed the log-in view controller after the UINavigationController, and because there's usually no navigation bar at the log-in view, i've hidden the navigation bar and showed it back again after the user logged in "when showing the MainViewController".
Hope this work around helps other people that run to this problem